# Where to put binary file?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, filesystem, lintian

I am packaging my own application into .deb. According to [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20141210051522/http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-prepare-a-compiled-application-for-ubuntu-software-center/), my compiled application should be installed in /opt/my-package. However, the tool Lintian reports such error:

```
E: dir-or-file-in-opt opt/my-package
```

The explanation is [here](https://lintian.debian.org/tags/dir-or-file-in-opt.html).

What should I do? Where do you install your own application?

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A package to be uploaded to the Debian repositories should avoid `/opt` and `/usr/local` - these directories are reserved for the local system administrator, as per the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html). The lintian tags reflect this. You should, instead, structure your package so that:

- executables go in `/usr/bin` (or `/usr/sbin`, as the case maybe)
- libraries go in `/usr/lib` or an appropriate subfolder thereof
- architecture-independent shared data in a subfolder in `/usr/share`, etc.

Consult [the Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s9.1) for more information.

If your package is for local use, you can go ahead and ignore that tag. You can create a [lintian override](https://lintian.debian.org/manual/section-2.4.html) to stop lintian from generating that error.